# delay() not working as expected inside of each() loop (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, foreach, each, delay

I have a series of elements that I want to toggle in-and-out of view sequentially. I am using a `<button class="toggle">` to control this:

```
$('.toggle').click(function(){
    $('.squares span').each(function(index){
      $(this).delay(600*index+1).toggleClass('hide');
    });
});
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/r2vk7L5b/

It appears that the `delay()` method is simply being ignored in this loop. The `index` variable is being passed as expected as well. You can console out to see it returning as 0,1,2,3, etc.

What here am I failing to understand about the `each()` or `delay()` method?

Comment: `.delay()` only works for animation queues. `.toggleClass()` does not create one. Use the good old `setTimeout()`, perhaps? Also, remember precedence in basic arithmetic: multiplication comes before addition. You should be using `600*(index+1)`, not `600*index+1`.

Comment: So my impression is that delay doesn't stack so it's jumping right to the next function call.  Here are some strategies for workarounds.  http://www.mattlunn.me.uk/blog/2012/06/jquery-delay-not-working-for-you/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`toggleClass` isn't one of jQuery's [animation (effects) functions](http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/) (like `fadeIn`), and `delay` only works with jQuery's animation functions. `toggleClass` (and `show` and `hide` and several other basic functions) are done *immediately*, even if there's a delay or other effects pending in the jQuery effects queue.

To simulate `delay` with a non-animation function, you can use `setTimeout`:

```
$('.toggle').click(function(){
    $('.squares span').each(function(index){
      var $this = $(this);
      setTimeout(function() {
          $this.toggleClass('hide');
      }, 600*index+1);
    });
});
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r2vk7L5b/4/)

Or alternately, consider using an animation (effects) function.

Comment: You'll see in my jsFiddle that I have a class that does hide the element. I do want to control this by adding or removing a class to the elements.

Comment: @invot: That's what the `setTimeout` version does. It does exactly what your `delay` version would have done, if `toggleClass` were one of jQuery's animation functions.

Comment: I was completely unaware of `toggleClass` not being an animation effect. I didn't know that `delay()` only worked with those.

Comment: @invot: You're not the first. :-) The fact that `delay` delays the effects of some functions and not others has tripped lots of people up (it's common to see people expecting it to work with `show` and `hide`, but the concept is the same here).